# How to create forwarder wallet in Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, wallets, wallet-transfer

I have more than one ETH wallet. I want to automatically combine these wallets into one wallet. For example, when I get an ETH in wallet 0x1, I want it to automatically transfer it to wallet 0x2. Can I do this with a smart contract? Or how can I do it?  Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple contract with a payable fallback function for this. For example:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;

contract Forwarder {
  address payable owner;
    
  constructor (address payable _owner)  {
    owner = _owner;
  }
  
  fallback () external payable {
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

Every time ETH is sent to the contract, the fallback function is called, which forwards the ETH (`msg.value`) to `owner`.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I want.  I want it transferred when ETH comes to my A wallet, not a contract.

Comment: You asked "Can I do this with a smart contract?", if you don't want to use a smart contract, you'll have to set up some kind of system that checks for incoming transactions, and automatically sends a new transaction. You can't pull ETH from an address with a smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a forwarder wallet, you instruct your user to transfer to an address which will automatically transfer inbound funds to a parent/central wallet.

Here's a project i created doing the same: https://github.com/farirat/solidity-forwarder-wallet

Run the tests and you will get the complete workflow.